# How to determine whether data in a column is in sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

For example: in a column there are some numbers. The question is to find the row number of the column where the sequence breaks.

```
Numbers  | 
:------- | 
1        | 
2        |
3        |
5        |
6        | 
8        |
11       |
12       |
15       |
```

[image]

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: what result you expect?

Comment: Search for Gaps and islands.

Comment: I honestly hope your professor asks you to explain the answer/homework. I have nothing against homework questions but blatantly posting the question verbatim with no attempt at an answer irritates me.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers will work assuming your sequence starts at 1. This will work regardless but may not be as efficient:

```
select min(t1.number) 
from Numbers As t1 
left outer join Numbers As t2 
  on t1.number = t2.number - 1 
where t2.number is null
```

Comment: No, @JohnCappelletti solution works regardless of the start point.

Comment: Even If there is no breaking point, this solution still returns the maximum number without any indication that this is not a breaking point.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your sample data, which is sequential starting with 1, you can use this.

```
create table #tt (i int)
insert into #tt (i) values
(1),(2),(4),(5)

;with cte as
    (select
        i,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by i) as rn
    from #tt)

select top 1 *
from cte where rn <> i
```

Here is a method for data not starting at 1.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tt') is not null drop table #tt
create table #tt (i int)
insert into #tt (i) values
(2),(3),(4),(5),(7),(8)

declare @min int = (select top 1 i from #tt order by i)

;with cte as
    (select
        i,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by i) as rn
    from #tt)


select top 1 *
from cte where rn + (@min - 1) <> i
```

Comment: But In that example `'5'` also break sequence?

Comment: what do you mean @JuanCarlosOropeza? OP wanted first instance of a missing value if i understood correctly.

Comment: well the OP sequence break in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, this is a classic Gaps and Islands question.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Numbers int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1),(2),(3),(5),(6),(8),(11),(12),(15)

Select NumR1 = min(Numbers)
      ,NumR2 = max(Numbers)
 From (
        Select *
              ,Island = Numbers - Row_Number() over (Order By Numbers)
         From  @YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Island
 Order By 1
```

Returns

```
NumR1   NumR2
1       3
5       6
8       8
11      12
15      15
```

> **Edit Optional after the Group By**

```
Having min(Numbers)<>max(Numbers)
```

or

```
Having min(Numbers)=max(Numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase the requirement, the goal is to provide a list of rows where the `Number` column does not continue a sequence of incrementing integers.  In other words, return all rows where no row exists containing `Number` minus one.

Once you put it that way, it's pretty easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0
                   FROM   MyTable
                   WHERE  Number = t.Number - 1)
```

Technically the row with `Number` = 1 does not continue a sequence (it starts one), so it'll be included in the above recordset.

If you want to remove it, but also be capable of supporting the data case where the numeric sequence starts with an arbitrary number that may or may not be 1,  you just need to know if there are any rows that contain a smaller number.

```
SELECT Number
FROM   MyTable t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0
                   FROM   MyTable
                   WHERE  Number = t.Number - 1)
AND    EXISTS     (SELECT 0
                   FROM   MyTable
                   WHERE  Number < t.Number)
```